# Parameter value for an drop down select list in html

Tags: html, servlets

I'm trying to get the value you select in a drop Down list in html into my servlet. 
I have created the drop Down list in html like this showed under here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeldk/TFPX2/3/

What should i write in my servlet, to request the value from the drop Down?

Normally i do it like:

```
String Name = request.getParameter("name");
```

I want to get the value you select in the drop Down, into my servlet.

```
String food = request.getParameter("???")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a name for Select option.

```
<select name="food">
<option value="none">Please Select fav food</option>
<option value="Salt">Pizza</option>
<option value="Clorid">Lasagne</option>
</select>
```

and call it in your servlet program.

```
String food = request.getParameter("food")
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could enter the name in the select.